# EReadError with TColor published properties in FMX

Tags: firemonkey

In an FMX component, I have this definition:

```
published
  property BackgroundColor: TColor read fBackgroundColor write fBackgroundColor;
end;
```

If BackgroundColor is set to a const, like clRed, then I get an EReadError "Error reading BackgroundColor: Invalid property value".

It works with a normal value, like $00FF8000. So why does the Object inspector let you select a const???

The workaround is to declare the property as TAlphaColor, but that means *another* conditional define in my combined VCL/FMX unit.

Is there any other way I can keep the property as TColor?

Delphi 10.3.2

Comment: Which class does the BackgroundColor belong to? What is the type of this BackgroundColor? I believe that the type is TAlphaColor any you can not assign a TColor to a TAlphaColor.

Comment: It descends from TControl which does not have a BackgroundColor property. It is a field fBackgroundColor: TColor;

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mix `TColors` with `TColor`. Both are defined in `System.UITypes`:

```
TColor = -$7FFFFFFF-1..$7FFFFFFF;

TColors = TColorRec;
TColorRec = record ...
```

From Vcl.Graphics:

```
clRed = TColors.Red;
```

Maybe the following function could help you to convert the types

```
function AlphaColorToColor(const Color: TAlphaColor): TColor;
```

Unfortunately, No function `ColorToAlphaColor` is available in `System.UITypes`.

Uwe Raabe has published an own solution in the DelphiPraxis forum for this purpose:

```
function ColorToAlphaColor(Value: TColor): TAlphaColor;
var
  CRec: TColorRec;
  ARec: TAlphaColorRec;
begin
  CRec.Color := Value;
  ARec.A := CRec.A;
  ARec.B := CRec.B;
  ARec.G := CRec.G;
  ARec.R := CRec.R;
  Result := ARec.Color;
end;
```

See also here [Convert TColor in TAlphaColor](https://www.delphipraxis.net/182406-tcolor-talphacolor-unwandeln.html)

Comment: For a TColor property, the object inspector allows you to choose VCL colors like clRed or clBtnFace. It just can handle the streaming if you do.

Comment: Ok, but that must be an issue in the Delphi IDE. Can you add an error report for it in the quality central: https://quality.embarcadero.com?